# Как использовать иммутабельные запросы в WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, сериализация

Есть проект, в котором надо контракты дополнительно к webapi выставить и по wcf. При этом контракты сделаны иммутабельными: нет parameterless конструктора по умолчанию, свойства get-only, всё под функциональный стиль:

```
public class ExportClientRequest
{
    public ExportClientRequest(int clientId)
    {
        this.ClientId = clientId;
    }

    public int ClientId { get; }
}
```

Замечательно сериализуется/десериализуется привычным Json.Net уже даже можно не вешать `[JsonConstructor]` для подсказок как создавать экземпляр класс.

```
[Test]
public void JsonSerialize()
{
    var request = new ExportClientRequest(42);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExportClientRequest>(json);

    Assert.That(request.ClientId, Is.EqualTo(deserialized.ClientId));
}
```

Однако как только начинаешь работать с WCF начинаются проблемы с сериализацией, там штатно всё это идёт через XmlSerializer, поэтому тесты на де/сериализацию начинают выдавать ошибку за ошибкой:

```
[Test]
public void XmlSerialize()
{
    var request = new ExportClientRequest(42);

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExportClientRequest));

    using var writer = new StringWriter();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, request);

    using var reader = new StringReader(writer.ToString());

    var deserialized = (ExportClientRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    Assert.That(request.ClientId, Is.EqualTo(deserialized.ClientId));
}
```

Сначала оно жалуется на отсутствие безпараметрического конструктора:

> System.InvalidOperationException :
> CompanyName.ProjectName.Contracts.ExportClientRequest cannot be
> serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Окей, добавил, навесив [Obsolete] чтобы находить в коде места где будут использовать не по назначению.

Потом тест стал ругаться на private set'тер:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot deserialize type
> 'CompanyName.ProjectName.Contracts.ExportClientRequest' because it
> contains property 'ClientId' which has no public setter.

(При этом ни protected, ни internal ему не подходит - только публичный).

И я что-то тихо выпадаю в осадок: это вообще реально работать с иммутабельностью в WCF или только "никак", возвращаемся обратно:

```
public class ExportClientRequest
{
    [Obsolete]
    internal ExportClientRequest()
    {
    }

    public ExportClientRequest(int clientId)
    {
        this.ClientId = clientId;
    }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Почитал на en so темы, но чего-то утешительного не нашёл, ну например: [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267724/5752652) -- типа проблема by design. :(

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/267724/5752652

Comment: _всё это идёт через XmlSerializer_ - судя по этим словам, я думал, вы намеренно отказались от `DataContractSerializer'а`.

Answer (score 2):

Предложу следующее решение.

Реализовать интерфейс `IXmlSerializable`. Причём явно: тогда методы этого интерфейса не будет видны на экземплярах `ExportClientRequest`.

Беспараметрический конструктор при этом можно сделать приватным (но он всё же нужен).

Для свойства придётся ввести поле, чтобы задавать его в методе `ReadXml`.

В итоге внешне класс получается чистым: методы интерфейса не видны (если не знать, что он реализует интерфейс), конструктор не виден. Красота!

Но придётся вручную описывать процесс записи в `XmlWriter` и чтение из `XmlReader`. Это огромный недостаток.

```
public class ExportClientRequest : IXmlSerializable
{
    ExportClientRequest() { }

    public ExportClientRequest(int clientId)
    {
        _clientId = clientId;
    }

    private int _clientId;
    public int ClientId => _clientId;

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("ClientId");
        _clientId = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(nameof(ClientId), ClientId.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Можно сделать объекты просто ISerializable и реализовать в обьектах дополнительно код для сериализации и конструктор для десериализации.
   Вот здесь в самом конце такой вариант описан, да и вообще все варианты:
   https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/serialization-guidelines
2. А можно привязать к контракту WCF реализацию IDataContractSurrogate и всю логику по сериализации и десериализации запихнуть в него

Второй вариант позволит прикрутить WCF не затрагивая остальной код, но придется фактически под каждый класс сделать дубликат, который будет конвертироваться туда-сюда.

Answer (score 1):

Зря я поленился написать реальное приложение сначала — а пробовал написать тест с мыслью "а потом уже допишу приложение".

Да, оно тоже не работает, но в exception вендор оставил подсказку, куда двигаться:

> 2020-11-16 12:54:40,308 [ExportClient, 1] - Unhandled exception on
> start.System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Тип
> "'CompanyName.ProjectName.Contracts.ExportClientRequest" не может быть
> сериализован. Пометьте его с помощью атрибута DataContractAttribute, а
> также пометьте все его члены, которые необходимо сериализовать, с
> помощью атрибута DataMemberAttribute. Если этот тип является
> коллекцией, пометьте его атрибутом CollectionDataContractAttribute.
> Для получения сведений о других поддерживаемых типах см. документацию
> к Microsoft .NET Framework.

(Вот почему сообщение по-русски, хотя в студии язык английский и русский снесён сто лет назад? Это же боль просто если бы пришлось гуглить пытаясь угадать исходное сообщение на английском)

Итого, вот такой вариант в приложении работает без проблем и вполне меня устраивает:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace CompanyName.ProjectName.Contracts
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ExportClientRequest
    {
        public ExportClientRequest(int clientId)
        {
            this.ClientId = clientId;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int ClientId { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

И тогда уже тест переписывается в такую форму:

```
/// <summary>
/// For WCF.
/// </summary>
[Test]
public void DataContractSerialize()
{
    var request = new ExportClientRequest(42);

    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ExportClientRequest));

    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings());
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, request);
    writer.Close();

    stream.Position = 0;

    var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings());

    var deserialized = (ExportClientRequest)serializer.ReadObject(reader);

    Assert.That(request.ClientId, Is.EqualTo(deserialized.ClientId));
}
```

Очень близко намёк был и в вопросах, которые я читал, просто я его проглядел, не подумал, что мне можно уйти от XmlSerialize:

> This is a limitation of `XmlSerializer`. Note that `BinaryFormatter`
> and `DataContractSerializer` *do not* require this - they can create
> an uninitialized object out of the ether and initialize it during
> deserialization.

Comment: Сообщение вам выдаёт не студия, а стандартная библиотека, которая смотрит на язык системы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ага, вот что значит я забыл сделать, когда мне в этот раз винду переставили на компе! Спасибо за совет!